# How to remove or hide empty tag that is inside another tag in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `html` file which uses `Angular js` as the framework. I use `Angular js` to process certain data and display it in the `html` inside the a span tag like below

```
<span>
    <span>
        <b ng-if="some condition">some data</b>
    </span>
    <span>
        <b>some data</b>
    <span>
</span>
```

Now when the condition doesn't match, the content of `b` tags are empty. This creates extra whitespace for those conditions in the page.

I have tried the below `css` trick to hide such tags altogether.

```
span b:empty {
        display: none;
        }
```

But this didn't work out. I still see empty content (whitespaces) for those tags. What do I do? I am also open to the idea of using `Javascript` to scan and hide those elements.

Comment: ng-if normally doesn't add to the dom if the condition doesnt match. can you check those white spaces are due to ng-if only. an example jsfiddle or something would help to check.

Comment: @PDKPavanKumar Sorry, I guess I gave a wrong example. I have edited the html code to reflect the problem I am facing.

Comment: I tested your code and the `display: none;` seems to work. But `<b>` tags are inline elements so without other styles, they do not add space on the page.

Comment: Just add <span> tag and add only that <b> tag inside <span> tag and give ng-if for span not for <b> tag. Just give a try. But ng-if should hide the space. Not sure why its giving space.

Comment: guys! I have edited the html code to show accurately what I am facing. I am sorry for the frequent edits since this html code is not written by me and hence I am trying to understand it, debug it and then trying to explain the problem to you guys.

Comment: Have you tried what @ChandanYS suggested? `<span ng-if="some condition"><b>some data</b></span>`